# SpringBoot. ResponseBodyAdvcie after ExcpeitonHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

I got 2 `@ControllerAdvice` interceptors

1 - adivce for wrap response body to default response wrapper object

```java
@ControllerAdvice
class BodyWrapper implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
       
       @Override
       public Object beforeBodyWrite(
            Object body,
            MethodParameter returnType,
            MediaType selectedContentType,
            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
            ServerHttpRequest request,
            ServerHttpResponse response) {
                 return new DataResponse(body);
            }
}
```

2 - exception handler

```java
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {MyCustomException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<?> handleCustomExceptions(
            MyCustomException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(
                        ex.getMsg().getStatus().getCode())
                .body(ex.getReason().getPayload());
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

`ResponseBodyAdvice` catches any exceptions and then the `ExceptionHandler` is not called.
How to prevent invoking `ResponseBodyAdvice` if any exception occurs? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to order the interceptors you can do it with `@Order` annotation

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {MyCustomException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<?> handleCustomExceptions(
            MyCustomException ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(
                        ex.getMsg().getStatus().getCode())
                .body(ex.getReason().getPayload());
    }
}
```

In this sample I have added the constant to highest order but you can use numeric order.

Comment: Unfortunately not work :(